# Серверные платформы для создания многопользовательской игры

Tags: разработка-игр

Всем привет, кто откликнулся. Какие серверные платформы посоветуете использовать для создания многопользовательской игры? Может я не совсем корректно задал свой вопрос, но попробую описать суть более подробно.

Решили написать многопользовательскую игру, ну там, где есть мир, разделённый на небольшие локации, где бегают другие игроки и стоят мобы. Совсем простенькую без наворотов. Где будет осуществляться перемещение и атака кликом мышки.
Имеется опыт создания Node.js приложений, поэтому в первую очередь пришла мысль написать сервер на этой платформе. И сразу возникает вопрос, что лучше использовать в качестве транспорта - готовую Socket.IO библиотеку, или лучше самому написать с 0 на сокетах предоставляемых Node.js?! Кстати, клиентская часть написана на flash.

P.S. Слышал, что для многопользовательского сервера отлично подходит Jawa, но я, к сожалению, с ней не работал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Знаете `Node.JS`, но не знаете `Java`? Пишите на `Node.JS`.

`Socket.IO` или свой транспорт? Т.к. основная идея `Socket.IO` состоит в реализации сокетов для `JavaScript'a`, скорее всего, лучше отказаться от использования оного ( откровенно говоря, вообще не вижу ему применения в контексте сабжа).

Вообще, ИМХО, если вы хотите написать столь сложный софт как многопользовательская игра ( даже без наворотов :D ), нужно, как не странно, поменьше думать и побольше делать. Иначе вы не напишите ее никогда.

Comment: "нужно, как не странно, поменьше думать и побольше делать. Иначе вы не напишите ее никогда". Однозначно, правы!

Comment: > нужно, как не странно, поменьше думать и побольше делать.

Вот так и рождается индусский код.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov - вы слишком буквально восприняли мое высказывание.

Я не имел введу - писать код не думая, имел введу - не стоит так много тратить время на выбор технологий, шаблонов, редактора etc. т.к., если вы хотите дописать многопользовательскую игру при жизни - у вас нет на это времени, а не то, о чем подумали вы.

К тому-же, как раз для тех, кто может неправильно меня воспринять или понять было написано *ИМХО* и, как-бы, это лишь дополнение к ответу, сам ответ написан в первых двух абазацах или и там вы с чем-то не согласны?

Comment: А хотя, к черту, минусуйте меня полностью :D

Comment: Не представляю, как эту фразу можно было воспринять иначе. 

Написание кода занимает 10% от общего времени. Все остальное время уходит на разработку архитектуры, проектирование, выбор технологий, etc. Причем последнее не менее важно, поскольку смена неудачно выбранной технологии в будущем, как правило, влечет за собой полное переписывание всей системы. И как следствие, нехватка времени из-за непродуманной архитектуры и некачественного труднорасширяемого кода.

Поэтому именно, что нужно побольше думать и только потом делать. Иначе это все будет напоминать анекдот: Что тут думать? Прыгать надо!

Comment: С первым абзацем согласен в плане, что технология в которой уже есть опыт предпочтительнее.

Comment: "Написание кода занимает 10% от общего времени". Разве что в параллельной вселенной.

Вообще я тоже люблю идеализировать, но простите - люди никогда не писали игры, соответственно они:



 - не могут знать что именно им подходит, а что нет


 - далеко не всегда знают как решать ту или иную проблему
Соответственно смена технологий и **много** плохого (неправильного etc.) кода по определению, во всяком случае на первых стадиях, не избежать.

"Что тут думать? Прыгать надо!". Как не странно, я считаю что именно так и нужно делать.

Comment: Разумеется, 10% - это в идеальном случае. На говнокод приходится тратить *значительно* больше.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov - о прототипах, как я понимаю, вы ничего не слышали.

Вообще - нет желания с вами спорить, на самом деле, тема крайне холиварна и правильно ответа, во всяком случае в вопросе - как делать, нет. (вернее у каждого он свой)

Comment: Я услышал то что хотел, а именно
"Socket.IO или свой транспорт? Т.к. основная идея Socket.IO состоит в реализации сокетов для JavaScript'a, скорее всего, лучше отказаться от использования оного"
Спасибо.